# How can I check whether the variable have value or not?

Tags: java

I new to `Java`.Might be it's a simple question,but I didn't get it.

I have variable, I want to check whether that variable have a value or not.For This I wrote the following code.But every time it showing `false` as a output.

```
public class StringOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Boolean b=new Boolean("T87778rue");
        int i = 10;
        System.out.println(b.equals(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `b` supposed to be?

Comment: Well, `"1+2"+3;` will result in an output of the string `"1+23"`. Were you trying to do `1 + 2 + 3`? Also, where is `b` defined?

Comment: @All Sorry Guys, I update my question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You've completely changed the code...

Comment: if(b == null){ do x} else if(b == true) { do y } else { do z cause b is false}

Comment: In what world would you expect "T87778rue" to be equal to 10?!

Comment: By definition, if the Java program compiles, the variable has a value at all places where it's value is referenced.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense , not sure if it compiles either !

Comment: @HotLicks Ish, it could be null (not primative types I know)

Comment: @All I am just trying to understand `equals()` in `Boolean` class.

Comment: @RichardTingle - null is a value.

Comment: @RichardTingle, L33tWUR1d.

Comment: @HotLicks Hence "ish" but its the bare minimum of having a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a Boolean object representing a false value, because the string parameter is not "true" (ignoring case).

```
Boolean b=new Boolean("T87778rue");
```

Next, you check whether the Boolean object representing false is equal to 10. It's not.

```
int i = 10;
System.out.println(b.equals(i));
```

From the Boolean constructor API documentation:

> Boolean(String s)
>   Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if it compiles, the variable has a value.

Initially it might have a default value, and that value might be null, but it always has a knowable value.

In you case you appear to be asking if a String can be evaluated as an expression.  That is a very different subject and you can evaluate an expression in Java.

BTW `"1+2"+3` = `"1+23"` as you are doing a string operation.

> .But every time it showing false as a output.

It should be false, every time as the values are the same every time. A Boolean is parsed as true, only is it is "true" ignoring the case.  You Boolean is false and this is not the same an `Integer` which is 10, and it is never the same.

---

And example of accessing a field before it is initialised

```
public enum Main {
    ;

    static {
        printInJ();
    }

    static final int i = Integer.parseInt("100");
    static final int j = 100;

    private static void printInJ() {
        System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    }

    static {
        printInJ();
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
    }
}
```

prints

```
i = 0, j = 100
i = 100, j = 100
```

Comment: `int n;` compiles on its own, so what is the value of `n`?

Comment: @arshajii I believe 0, all primatives have default values

Comment: `n = 0;` if it compiles. All numbers are `0`, boolean is `false` and all references are `null`, even if you access them before they are initialised.

Comment: Then why do I have to explicitly set `n = 0` in order to use it, if it has a knowable value as you claim? I'm talking about a local variable.

Comment: @arshajii, The local variable `int n;` by itself only compiles when `n` is not read, so does not observably not have a value.  As a field, `int n` has the value `0i`.

Comment: @arshajii The compiler, pragmatically, says you cannot access a local variable until it knows it have initialised and you cannot set a final local variable which might have been initialised.  Member fields are much harder to reason about so they only have to be initialised if they are final.  You can still access them before they are set. (See above)

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. +1